# Directory created from within an emulator on Android Studio not showing up in adb

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adb

I'm building an app that (in SDK < 30) needs to list the files in a directory that, in testing, I've created through the emulator as I would on a physical device (from Files->SD card->Menu->New File "MyFiles").

My code throws a null-pointer exception on line three here:

```
        String path = "/storage/emulated/0/MyFiles";
        File directory = new File(path);
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: path to downloads dir is " + path);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + files.toString());
        Log.d("Files", "Size: " + files.length);
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            Log.d("Files", "FileName: " + files[i].getName());
```

And when I go through the file system on adb, my new directory is nowhere to be found! Am I doing something wrong, or are user-created directories just globally non-accessible?

What I'm trying to do is make an app that reads epubs, and ideally I would like to have it offer the user a choice of directories to choose on install (the kindle folder, downloads, or some arbitrary Ebook folder if they store their files somewhere else). If this is the wrong approach entirely I'd be happy to hear of other paths toward that goal.